# OctoberCMS adding backend administrator fields with validation

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins, october-form-controller

I want to add few more fields in my **backend administrator** by creating my own plugin called as **Users**. Here is what I have done so far to create few new fields.

**plugins\technobrave\users\Plugin.php**

```
<?php namespace Technobrave\Users;

use System\Classes\PluginBase;
use Backend\Models\User as BackendUserModel;
use Backend\Controllers\Users as BackendUsersController;
class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function registerComponents()
    {
    }

    public function registerSettings()
    {
    }

    public function boot()
    {
          // Add college and teacher field to Users table
        BackendUserModel::extend(function($model){
            $model->belongsTo['team'] = ['technobrave\team\Models\Team'];            

        });




         // Add college and teacher field to Users form
         BackendUsersController::extendFormFields(function($form, $model, $context){

            if (!$model instanceof BackendUserModel)
                return;

            $form->addTabFields([
                'team' => [
                    'label'   => 'Team',
                    'comment' => 'Associate this user with a team.',
                    'type' => 'recordfinder',
                    'list' => '$/technobrave/team/models/team/columns.yaml',
                    'prompt' => 'Click the %s to find a team',
                    'select' => 'id',
                    'nameFrom'=> 'name',
                    'tab' => 'Account'
                ]
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

**plugins\technobrave\users\models\User.php**

```
<?php namespace Technobrave\Users\Models;

use Model;


/**
 * Model
 */
class User extends Model
{



    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;

    /*
     * Validation
     */
    public $rules = [
        'team_id' => 'required',

    ];

    public $customMessages = [
                'team_id.required' => 'Please select Team',




    ];

    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'backend_users';
}
```

And now this is how my **Administrator** page looks like.

[image]

And if I click on "Team Recordfinder" I am able to see like below.

[image]

And if I select any of the team record from the list, its looks like below.

[image]

As you can see all working fine so far. But as soon as I fill full form, I am getting this SQL error saying column not found. Like below.

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'team_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `backend_users` (`is_superuser`, `login`, `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `persist_code`, `permissions`, `team_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (0, Johny, johny@mailinator.com, Johny, Cook, y$bbr00J5O2dE1WDHHWZYHIeMduXI82HkDnE8IYBcAet4ie0nfpgpwq, , , 9, 2017-05-19 06:23:49, 2017-05-19 06:23:49))" on line 666 of C:\xampp\htdocs\slp_website_cms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php

[image]

Now, My question is, **do I need to add `team_id` field manually in *backend_users* table ? Is it valid way ? I am not sure.**

Additionally, I want to make validations for this particular field hence I did below.

**plugins\technobrave\users\models\User.php**

```
<?php namespace Technobrave\Users\Models;

use Model;


/**
 * Model
 */
class User extends Model
{



    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;

    /*
     * Validation
     */
    public $rules = [
        'team_id' => 'required',

    ];

    public $customMessages = [
                'team_id.required' => 'Please select Team',




    ];

    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'backend_users';
}
```

But validations are not working either. How can I validate this field if some one checked "Property Consultant" from User Role ?

Lot of questions but I need a best way to approach towards this issue. Can someone guide me to make this thing work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I need to add team_id field manually in backend_users table ? Is it valid way ? I am not sure.

Yes, you need to create a migration to add this field to the table.

For adding validation rules you also can extend model:

```
public function boot() { 
    BackendUserModel::extend(function($model){
         $myrules = $model->rules;
         $myrules['team_id'] = 'required';
         $model->rules = $myrules;
    });
}
```

For getting logged in user you can use App::before

```
public function boot() { 
    \App::before(function() { 
        // Here BackendAuth::getUser() is already initialized 
    )};
}
```

Comment: maybe add rule "required_if:field,value,..."?

Comment: Since the field "user_group_id" is in another table (backend_userS_groups), you will most likely need to write a Custom validation rule for this
https://octobercms.com/docs/services/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: For getting logged in user you can use App::before `public function boot() { \App::before(function() { // Here BackendAuth::getUser() is already initialized } } `